# Python3 'Cannot import name 'cached_property'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot get this to work. I keep adding modules and there's a new one not found each time. Why doesn't this code work in Python3.6?

Code:

```
from robobrowser import robobrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib
from werkzeug import werkzeug
from cached_property import cached_property

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = robobrowser.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://www.cbssports.com/login")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['userid'] = 'steveb1164'
br.form['password'] = ''
br.submit()

print(br.response().read())
```

Run:

```
RESTART: C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/CBSlogin.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/CBSlogin.py", line 1, in <module>
    from robobrowser import robobrowser
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\robobrowser\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .browser import RoboBrowser
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\robobrowser\browser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from werkzeug import cached_property
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property'
```

Comment: Do you have a python file called `werkzeug.py` in the current directory?

Comment: Can you try if just the line `from werkzeug import cached_property` works?

Comment: I have the werkzeug folder in site-packages

Comment: Joe, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/CBSlogin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from werkzeug import cached_property
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property'

Answer (score 26):

I got the werkzeug app running in Python 3.6 by inserting those lines before the Flask importing:

```
import werkzeug
werkzeug.cached_property = werkzeug.utils.cached_property
```

Comment: Inserting this before `import robobrowser` solved the problem for me

Comment: you save my day!

Answer (score 11):

If you are seeing this while using Flask Rest-Plus, there is an issue raised with the development team

https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/777

As observed:

"Downgrading to Werkzeug to 0.16.0 (temporarily) resolved the issue."

Comment: Also an issue with flask-testing.  Same recommendation. https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/143

Comment: From what I understand restplus is now defunct and Flask RESTX is taking its place as a direct fork. https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen: I'm new to restplus and this might be the case like you stated, but RESTX seems to have the same conflict with wekzeug. Lucioric2000's answer should work in either restplus or RESTX.

Comment: @HansGoldman I haven't checked, but my impression was that it was worked around in flask-restx 0.1.1, no? In anycase we migrated to restx a few months ago. And this isn't an issue any more. Will probably just replace the whole thing with fastapi anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a late response, but I may have found a solution.

You need to rename from werkzeug import cached property to the following:

```py
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall the werkzeug package by running - **pip uninstall werkzeug**
2. Reinstall the werkzeug package by running - **pip install werkzeug**
3. Add
   **import werkzeug
   werkzeug.cached_property = werkzeug.utils.cached_property** this to your code.

I hope its gonna work, cause it just worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue.
My python version is `3.7.3` and was using `Werkzeug` version `1.0.1`

I downgraded the `Werkzeug` version to `0.16.0` and it worked

```
pip install --upgrade Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Try reinstalling the `werkzeug` package.

```
pip uninstall Werkzeug
pip install Werkzeug
```